# Display a javascript var in html body

Tags: javascript, html, display

I want to display text on the webpage as below but really couldn't figure out, thank you so much!

"The sum of all odd numbers till 100 is: _

The sum of all even numbers till 100 is: _"

````
var operator = 'addition'; 
var i = 1;                 
var msg = '';              

if (operator === 'addition') {
  // Do addition
  while (i < 11) {
    msg += i + ' + ' + table + ' = ' + (i + table) + '<br />';
    i++;
  }
} else {
  // Do multiplication
  while (i < 11) {
    msg += i + ' x ' + table + ' = ' + (i * table) + '<br />';
    i++;
  }
}

// Create the sun of all odd numbers

var oddNumber = "The sum of all odd numbers till 100 is:";
var evenNumber = "The sum of all even numbers till 100 is: ";
var oddSum = 0;
var evenSum = 0;

for (i=1; i<100; i=i+2){ oddSum += i;
}
for (i=0; i<100; i=i+2){ evenSum += i;
}

oddNumber += oddSum;
evenNumber += evenSum;

var msg1 = oddNumber + "<br>" + evenNumber;



var el = document.getElementById('blackboard');
el.innerHTML = msg1 + "<br>" + "<br>" + msg2 + "<br>" + "<br>" + msg;```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for you. You have few syntax errors in your code. Also you can not add innerHTML until and unless DOM is loaded.

```html
<script>
var operator = 'addition'; 
var i = 1;                 
var msg = '';

var oddNumber = "The sum of all odd numbers till 100 is:";
var evenNumber = "The sum of all even numbers till 100 is: ";
var oddSum = 0;
var evenSum = 0;

for (i=1; i<100; i=i+2){ oddSum += i;
}
for (i=0; i<100; i=i+2){ evenSum += i;
}

oddNumber += oddSum;
evenNumber += evenSum;

var msg1 = oddNumber + "<br>" + evenNumber;

console.log(msg1);

window.onload = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('blackboard');
    el.innerHTML = msg1;
}
</script>

<div id="blackboard"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you were missing declaring variables `table` and `msg2`. After adding them bellow `msg`, the code works. I hope this is helpful!

```js
var operator = 'addition'; 
var i = 1;                 
var msg = '';    
var table = '';
var msg2 = '';

if (operator === 'addition') {
  // Do addition
  while (i < 11) {
    msg += i + ' + ' + table + ' = ' + (i + table) + '<br />';
    i++;
  }
} else {
  // Do multiplication
  while (i < 11) {
    msg += i + ' x ' + table + ' = ' + (i * table) + '<br />';
    i++;
  }
}

// Create the sun of all odd numbers

var oddNumber = "The sum of all odd numbers till 100 is:";
var evenNumber = "The sum of all even numbers till 100 is: ";
var oddSum = 0;
var evenSum = 0;

for (i=1; i<100; i=i+2){ oddSum += i;
}
for (i=0; i<100; i=i+2){ evenSum += i;
}

oddNumber += oddSum;
evenNumber += evenSum;

var msg1 = oddNumber + "<br>" + evenNumber;



var el = document.getElementById('blackboard');
el.innerHTML = msg1 + "<br>" + "<br>" + msg2 + "<br>" + "<br>" + msg;
```

```html
<div id="blackboard"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
var operator = 'addition'; 
var i = 1;                 
var msg = '';

var oddNumber = "The sum of all odd numbers till 100 is:";
var evenNumber = "The sum of all even numbers till 100 is: ";
var oddSum = 0;
var evenSum = 0;

for (i=1; i<100; i=i+2){ oddSum += i;
}
for (i=0; i<100; i=i+2){ evenSum += i;
}

oddNumber =oddNumber+ oddSum;
evenNumber = evenNumber+ evenSum;

var msg1 = oddNumber + "<br>" + evenNumber;

console.log(msg1);

window.onload = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('blackboard');
    el.innerHTML = msg1;
}
</script>

<div id="blackboard"></div>
```